# Unable to log back in to Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, login

I have to ask this from meta.stackoverflow, because I am unable to log in to meta.stackexchange, so feel free to migrate this question.

I logged out of the workplace Stack Exchange site so I could ask a question anonymously. I am now unable to log in to the workplace Stack Exchange site, or many other communities where I am a member. This only affects the device where I logged out of the workplace Stack Exchange site. I am still logged in to stack overflow.

For instance, I am a member of the security Stack Exchange site. This is what I see.

[image: Security Stack Exchange]

I don't see an option to log in. I then click Join this community and see this.

[image: Join this community]

I still do not see an option to log in. When I use Google to try to join this community, it brings me back to what you see in the first image, with me still not logged in.

This is all in the same browser that I am currently logged into Stack Overflow. I don't know what to try next. I've read [the Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), but I don't see anything there that helps with this situation.

What seems to be happening is that Stack Exchange has created an unfinished account for me when I made the anonymous post, so I'm technically already logged in, but not in my primary account, but in the temporary account made for me.

**How can I log back into Stack Exchange?**

Comment: When I'm logged into Stack Overflow and go to the Information Security stack exchange site, it only gives the "Join this community" option, however, when I'm logged out of Stack Overflow and I go to that site, it shows both "Log in" and "Join this community". Perhaps your Stack Overflow `Goose` account isn't the same one you registered for Security Stack Exchange or any of the others? The log-in system expects you to use the same account between all stack exchange sites.

Comment: @DavyM What seems to be happening is that Stack Exchange has created an unfinished account for me when I made the anonymous post, so I'm technically already logged in, but not in my primary account, but in the temporary account made for me.

Answer (score 2):

Going to workplace.stackexchange.com, viewing my profile, and deleting it, automatically logged me into my normal stack exchange account. Kind of strange behavior. Next time I need to post a question anonymously, I'll just use a different browser.

Comment: Yeah, I hesitate to call this "by design", but anonymous posting and multiple accounts are not supported well at all (and consequently discouraged). We should, perhaps, at least prevent posting as unregistered (like you did) when we know you're logged in (and thus show you the "join the community" button.

Comment: @AdamLear yeah, I wouldn't have minded being prevented from getting in this situation.